# How can we write json schema for multiple html form in a single html page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am using HTML along with Bootstrap and angular.

I have 2 forms (same page, not nested),

- Search form (fetch data from db using spring boot)
- Input form for inserting data to db

How can I write the JSON schema for this file? Do we need to write separate code for two form?

```
Form 1: 
name=SearchForm                             

Form 2:
name=inputForm
1. Name
2. Age
3. Sports 
    - 1.Cricket
    - 2.Soccer
    - 3.Tennis
```

-A button when clicked additional details can be entered(type Array)

```
--Marks in Subject 1
- Marks in Subject 2
- Marks in Subject 3
- Marks in Subject 4
- Marks in Subject 5
```

Also, please suggest some JSON books which I can refer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you dont need to create json schema models are created automatically your just need to name the models

Comment: it ok with the first form, but when I click add details(subject marks button) it is submitting form data but function name and model are different. Can we use both ng-submit and ng-click. Will it be a little messy. console.log working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. For search 
   html

   ```
   <input type="search" ng-model="searchData">
   ```

angualrjs script

now $scope.searchData contains the input value. use it for filtering the search data

2.Submiting the form details to db

```
<form name="inputForm">
<input type="text" ng-model="formData.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="formData.age">
<button ng-click="formSubmit(formData)"></button>
</form>
```

script code:

```
 $scope.formSubmit=function(formData){
      //formData contains the form data in json schema
     console.log(formData);
    //now pass the formData to your db
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Harish98  But I need to write a JSON schema for these two forms. How to write the JSON schema.

Comment: But @Harish98, from my knowledge, ng-submit should be used at form level. Can it be used with button?

Comment: use ng-click for button. ng-submit is for form level. we need to add attribute beside the form ng-submit to post form data

Comment: it ok with the first form, but when I add next details(subject marks) it is submitting form data but function name and model are different. Can we use both ng-submit and ng-click. Will it be a little messy. console working fine.